# How to access the original model inside of an ActiveRecord association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I've been using ActiveRecord association methods (such as in this post [Ryan's Scraps](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/12/3/extend-your-activerecord-association-methods)) to perform some of my more complex 2nd level associations, while minimizing query counts.  For example, I use the following association to pull all activity from everyone that a user follows (follow is a model that just contains the user_id and followed_user_id):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 <other associations, code, etc>
 has_many :follows do
 def activities(reload=false)
   @followed_activities = nil if reload
   @followed_activities ||= Activity.includes(:user, :comments, :comment_users).where(:user_id.in => self.collect {|e| e.followed_user_id}).order('activities.created_at DESC')
 end
 <.....>
end
```

This method has worked fantastically, no complaints.  However, the client has requested that activities from the user itself should be included (followed_users' activities + current_user's activities).

I realize this is probably ruby 101, but I can't figure out how to access User.id from the parent (User) model.  As you can see in the code, `self` refers to the follows relation, and returns a list of the matching rows from the follows table.

I kind of sort of got it to work sometimes by changing the following line:

```
@followed_activities ||= Activity.includes(:user, :comments, :comment_users).where(:user_id.in => (self.collect {|e| e.followed_user_id}) << self.first.user_id).order('activities.created_at DESC')
```

However, this a) feels very hackish, and b) raises an exception when there aren't any follows records (which is always the case with a new user).  How else can I get the user ID?

Comment: To give credit where it is due, I discovered this particular method in "Advanced Rails Recipes" sold by pragpub.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as seen in [the episode 215 Asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3), you can merge two relations using the `&` operator, so something like this should work:

```
@followed_activities    ||= Activity
                             .includes(:user, :comments, :comment_users)
                             .where(:user_id.in => (self.collect {|e| e.followed_user_id})
@current_users_activity ||= Activity
                             .includes(:user, :comments, :comment_users)
                             .where(:user_id.in => [self.first.user_id] )
@all_activities         ||= (@followed_activities & @current_users_activity).order('activities.created_at DESC')
```

**edit :**

note : in rails 3.1 the `&` operator is deprecated, use `Relation#merge` instead.

did some interesting research. This is definitely not "ruby 101" !

Actually, `self` in your code does refer to the [Association Proxy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy) between your `User` object and its associated `Follow` records. When you extend an association like this, you extend the proxy (as i barely understand it, the block is `instance_eval`'d against the proxy class).

in rails >= 3.1, there is a way to get your user id inside your block (see [this doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), section "association extension") :

```
proxy_association.owner.id
```

so you should be able to do :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :follows do

    def activities( reload = false )
      @followed_activities = nil if reload
      @followed_activities ||= begin
        Activity
          .includes( :user, :comments, :comment_users )
          .where( :user_id.in => [proxy_association.owner.id, *map( &:followed_user_id ) ])
          .order( 'activities.created_at DESC' )
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: That looks beautiful.  I will try that tonight and let you know.

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy delay, I got caught up in other things.  When I use the & (alias for merge), it adds the conditions from the two relations.  For example, if the first relation contains
    WHERE `activities`.`user_id` = 1
and the second contains
    WHERE `activities`.`user_id` IN (2)
then the new sql is
    WHERE `activities`.`user_id` = 1 AND `activities`.`user_id` IN (2)

This will return zero results.  How do I merge them with an "OR" instead of an "AND"?

Comment: This also doesn't answer the original question, since self.first.user_id will raise an exception if there are no follows, which was my original problem.

Comment: sorry, read it too fast. 1) try to use a "IN" clause in both statements, they should merge properly 2) did research on the subject, learned a lot of interesting things, edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for all the fun !

Comment: Thank you for a working solution and the matching documentation!  The actual method is proxy_association, not vice-versa.  Aside from that, it works beautifully!  Good thing I just upgraded to 3.1.3 :)